# Retrieving the top 5 sentences- Algorithm if any present

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, data-science

I am new to Data Science. This could be a dumb question, but just want to know opinions and confirm if I could enhance it well.
I have a question getting the most common/frequent 5 sentences from the database. I know I could gather all the data (sentences) into a list and using the Counter library - I could fetch the most occurring 5 sentences, but I am interested to know if any algorithm (ML/DL/NLP) is present for such a requirement. All the sentences are given by the user. I need to know his top 5 (most occurring/frequent) sentences (not phrases please)!!

**Examples of sentences** -

"Welcome to the world of Geeks"

"This portal has been created to provide well written subject"

"If you like Geeks for Geeks and would like to contribute"

"to contribute at geeksforgeeks org See your article appearing on "

"to contribute at geeksforgeeks org See your article appearing on " (occurring for the second time)

"the Geeks for Geeks main page and help thousands of other Geeks."

**Note**: All my sentences in my database are distinct (contextual wise and no duplicates too). This is just an example for my requirement.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Opinions, as well as "Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow - pls see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting

Comment: @desertnaut I think the question is not asking 'is this good or bad?' type of question but rather 'is there a sophisticated method to solve this problem?' type of question so I think it's still relevant. Maybe the use of the word 'opinion' is not used in the right sense

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to start with [sentence embeddings](https://towardsdatascience.com/sentence-embedding-3053db22ea77). Briefly, it returns a vector for a given sentence and it roughly represents the meaning of the sentence.

Let's say you have n sentences in your database and you found the sentence embeddings for each sentence so now you have n vectors.

Once you have the vectors, you can use dimensionality reduction techniques such as [t-sne](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) to visualize your sentences in 2 or 3 dimensions. In this visualization, sentences that have similar meanings should *ideally* be close to each other. That may help you pinpoint the most-frequent sentences that are also close in meaning.

I think one problem is that it's still hard to draw boundaries to the meanings of sentences since meaning is intrinsically subjective. You may have to add some heuristics to the process I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to MGoksu's answer, Once you get sentence embeddings, you can apply [LSH](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#locality-sensitive-hashing)(Locality Sensitive Hashing) to group the embeddings into clusters.

Once you get the clusters of embeddings. It would be a trivial to get the clusters with highest number of vectors.